# TeXstudio autocomplete label local definition

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I have a document with a local (not from package) defined commands

```
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\ref{#1}}
```

I know that I can use the TeXstudio autocomplete with a suggestion list by writing

```
\mylabel{label}#l
\myref{label}#r
```

in to a packagename.cwl file.
But is there an option to write it local into the document?

Comment: @ebo The point is that this is an minimal working example. There is some stuff that the command also does. I dont't just want the `\myref{arg1}` suggestion but the suggestions for all already existing labels like `\myref{label1}`, `\myref{label2}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently no way to write the definitions within the tex file.

Suggested workaround:

1. Create `[settings-directory]\completion\user\user.cwl` and define the command there.
2. Go to `Options -> Completion -> Permanently active completion files` and select `user.cwl` there.

Comment: Has this changed now?

Comment: No. This is the suggested way for the time being.